# MSBuild trying to build exe instead of dll

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have manually created a .csproj file to run using the command line tool msbuild, however, when I try run it it wants to build as an exe. How can I make it build exclusively as a dll? Here is the code in the .csproj file below and the command prompt I execute:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="System" />
        <Reference Include="System.Core" />
        <Reference Include="System.Data.Linq" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="C:\testing\test.cs" />
        <Compile Include="C:\testing\test.Designer.cs" />
        <EmbeddedResource Include="C:\testing\test.resx" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="Build">
        <Csc Sources="@(Compile)" 
             Resources="@(EmbeddedResource)" 
             References="@(Reference)" 
             TargetType="library"
             OutputAssembly="C:\testing\test.dll" />
    </Target>
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>

cmd: msbuild "C:\testing\test.csproj"
```

Comment: Though I can't say definitively, I believe getting rid of `TargetType` should clear it up. Based on the documentation the default `OutputType` is `Library`.

Comment: Is your `<Target Name="Build">` called? Isn't it overriden by the `Import`?

Comment: @rene honestly... I cannot say, I really only started looking at this just today. When I didn't have that Import in, it didn't compile

Comment: By far the best way to generate an msbuild script is to use the Visual Studio IDE.  The .csproj file it generates is good as-is.  You'll easily avoid mistakes like putting the `<Import>` tag in the wrong position so it replaces your `<Csc> target.

Comment: @HansPassant Unfortunately that is not an option in my case, I would gladly just leave the building up to VS

Comment: Not for building, for creating the file.  The Express edition is free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to your `csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Above the `<ItemGroup>` declaration.

Comment: Interesting. This doesn't seem to work with xbuild on mono systems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following to your project file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
  <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  <!-- Other properties go here -->
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
  <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  <!-- Other properties go here -->
</PropertyGroup>
```

You may have more platforms just add Library for whatever condition meets your need.

Or you can simply do:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
 <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
      <!-- Other properties go here -->
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
 <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
      <!-- Other properties go here -->
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This works because the build target from the import is used, right?

Answer (score 0):

Once you import the Microsoft.CSharp.targets file, you get the Build target all the ecosystem around it.

The following would work. Note the OutputType property.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Library</OutputType>    
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="System" />
        <Reference Include="System.Core" />
        <Reference Include="System.Data.Linq" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="Class1.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <!-- You don't need to call the Csc target as Build target is already there once you import the Microsoft.CSharp.targets file -->
    <!--<Target Name="Build">
        <Csc Sources="@(Compile)" 
             Resources="@(EmbeddedResource)" 
             References="@(Reference)" 
             TargetType="library"
             OutputAssembly="abc.dll" />
    </Target>-->
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it out...
You have to include these two lines in your .csproj file

```
<Project>
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Add Output Type -->
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
<!-- Add the MSBuildTools Targets as a reference -->
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

**One thing to Note:** A single project file can either create a WinExe Types or a Library Type...